# Display random text in React app with Math.random()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I previously had embedded this JS code inside an HTML page with this:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
    var r_text = new Array (); 
    r_text[0] = "\"This is a test\""; 
    r_text[1] = "\"This is another\""; 
    r_text[2] = "\"This is a test\""; 
    r_text[3] = "\"This is another\""; 
    var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random()); 
    
    document.write("<center>" + 
    r_text[i]  + "</center>"); 
    </SCRIPT>
```

It allows me to define a bunch of sentences and have a random one displayed each time the page loads.

I am now re-doing my site as a React app (and using TailwindCSS FWIW).

I tried dropping it directly like below:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div class="container mx-auto">

      <div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white text-center text-6xl m-10 overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
      site title
      </div>
    
    var r_text = new Array (); 
    r_text[0] = "\"This is a test\""; 
    r_text[1] = "\"This is another\""; 
    r_text[2] = "\"This is a test\""; 
    r_text[3] = "\"This is another\""; 
    var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random()); 
    
    document.write("<center>" + 
    r_text[i]  + "</center>");
```

This is not working, but I'm not sure how to make it compile.

Comment: Declare your variables **before** the `return` statement and then use `<center>{r_text[i]}</centre>` in the JSX although `<centre>` itself is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) so you should use something else. `document.write` has no place here (or anywhere else IMO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReactJS, it is advisable to perform all calculations before rendering the content. I advise you to read the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let r_text = new Array();
    r_text[0] = '"This is a test"';
    r_text[1] = '"This is another"';
    r_text[2] = '"This is a test"';
    r_text[3] = '"This is another"';

    var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());
    setText(r_text[i])
  },[])

  return (
    <div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white text-center text-6xl m-10 overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
        site title
      </div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks -- that worked! The last line `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` threw a `ReactDOM` not defined -- but I was able to remove the line and the code compiled.

Comment: yeah, this line is located in your `index.js`, it is needed in order to put your application in the `root` container in your `index.html`